# Notepad++ - Regex - Insert below matching line

Tags: notepad++

- Find what : `(\$apple)(?!.\$apple)`
- Replace : `\1\nFound`

Given:

```
$apple hello
```

After running code, I expect:

```
$apple hello
found
```

But its not working, I am getting :

```
$apple 
found hello
```

Comment: Did you mean like this `\$apple(?! \$apple) \S+` https://regex101.com/r/UGp3FZ/1

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\$apple(?!.*\$apple).*?\R`
- Replace with: `$0Found`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\$apple         # literally $apple
(?!.*\$apple)   # make we haven't $apple after
.*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\R              # any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          # the whole match, including linebreak
Found       # literally
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]